# Using Python Networkx and time series data

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, networkx

I read through the networkx documentation, but am having a hard time finding information about analyzing networks of time series data.

I am creating graph representing bank accounts (nodes) and transactions between them (edges). I need to be able to find paths and traverse the graph while respecting the time series order of the transactions.

For example:

```
import networkx as nx

G=nx.MultiGraph()
e=[('a','b',dict(value=1000, date='2017-01-01')),
   ('b','c',dict(value=500, date='2017-01-02')),
   ('c','d',dict(value=300, date='2017-01-01')),
   ('c','d',dict(value=500, date='2017-01-03'))]
G.add_edges_from(e)
```

From the edges above how could I return the transactions along the path `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`? This should give me should give me the transactions

```
a -> b on 'Jan 1'
b -> c on 'Jan 2' 
c -> d on 'Jan 3'
```

and not return `c -> d on 'Jan 1'`

Do I need to use a separate node to represent each account on a given date and a reference table to identify the account-date combinations?

Comment: What do 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' represent? you may need to write a custom graph traversal algorithm, which isn't difficult to do... To make the existing traversal algorithms work with no changes, you'd need to change the nodes to represent account state = (account, date), then edges are implicitly date ordered. Then, you find the path from one account state to another.

Comment: 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' represent unique (bank) accounts. The information to create the graph is stored in a SQL database, and ultimately I'd like to keep as much of the node and edge metadata in SQL as possible. It sounds like my options are either store the dates in the edges and write a custom traversal algorithm, or store the date in the node as part of the state (as you described it). I can see benefits to both, so maybe I just need to try each method and decide from there.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check out [Pathpy](https://github.com/IngoScholtes/pathpy). The library has been designed for the type of problems that you described.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I took a look at pathpy and it seems well suited for storing edges with time stamps (temporal networks per the author), however I didn't see any algorithms included to identify paths through the network. For example, I couldn't locate a function to return a path between node `u` and `v` in a temporal network. Did I overlook something?

Comment: Not quite sure if that's exactly what you need, but I think this is what you need (from [toturial](https://ingoscholtes.github.io/pathpy/tutorial.html)): We can access paths via a public dictionary paths, which contains the list (and frequencies) of paths of any length. For the example above, we can, e.g., access paths of length two as follows: `paths.paths[2]`, which gives you all paths with length 2 and the relevant nodes.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the `.paths[n]` method doesn't work with the `TemporalNetwork` class that holds time stamps for edges.

Comment: @Evan strange! I do remember that it worked for me. I will give it a try and let you know if I figure out anything new.